# Как прописать ::before внутри style=""?

Tags: html

```
<div class="hot-card" ::before="background:red;"></div>
```

Примерно так должно выглядить, но как реализовать не знаю может есть что-то подобное? Атрибуты там..
И нет через css и  не как потому-что у меня это нужно задать именно этому блоку, а если прописать в css то задаст всем..

Answer (score 1):

`::before` -- псевдоэлемент, а стили в атрибуте `style` вы прописываете для элемента, которому это свойство принадлежит. А раз элемент псевдо, то нет возможности задать его стиль таким образом.

Но выход есть. Вы можете использовать специальный класс для именно этого блока (атрибут `class` поддерживает несколько значений, например: `class="hot-card special-class"`) и всё-таки описать стили псевдоэлемента в css. Или вы можете создать настоящий элемент перед блоком и задать стили для него.

Comment: Не перед блоком, в первый _внутри_ блока

Comment: @Grundy вы правы

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [CSS переменные](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties):

```css
.hot-card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

.hot-card::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: var(--before-background, black);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="hot-card"></div>
<div class="hot-card" style="--before-background: red;"></div>
```

Или как предложил [@Егор Банин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/885895/221218) - использовать дополнительный класс для изменения псевдоэлементов.